# Shortcut to jump to factory definition with angularjs in Intellij

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, intellij-idea

Is there any shortcut to jump to a factory definition when you click on the usage of this factory in IntelliJ with AngularJS?

I have:

```
$scope.myFactory (in another controller)
```

and I want a fast way to jump to the definition of this factory:

```
angular.factory('myFactory', function(){....})
```